# JQuery Filer: Inserting download file link

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, upload

I'm using the library [**JQuery Filer**](http://filer.grandesign.md). It can upload files pretty well and can display the upload files.

I'm using templates to show the files icons (Like this [example](https://github.com/CreativeDream/jQuery.filer/blob/master/js/custom.js)).

I tried put a link to download file by clicking over the icon. So I put  the *href* for *itemAppend* template, but I need put the url.

```
  <a href=" ? "> 
   <div class="jFiler-item-inner">
     ...
   </div>
  </a>
```

Because I retrieve a Json object like this:

```
{    
 "name":"appended_file.jpg",
 "size":5453,
 "type":"image\/jpg",
 "file":"191a1a.jpg",
 "url":"http:\/\/dummyimage.com\/720x480\/f9f9f9\/191a1a.jpg"
}
```

But I don't found a way to use a *fi-** personalized variable ti insert the url in *href*. I would like something like '*fi-url*' to generate the link:

```
  <a href='{{fi-url}}'> 
   <div class="jFiler-item-inner">
     ...
   </div>
  </a>
```

I think it would be a good feature. Anyone knows if JQuery filer allows personalized fi-* variables or there another method to put the link.

Thanks

Comment: did you find any solution for this?